# How to schedule opening of command line or application in another PC

Tags: windows-xp, scheduled-task

I am trying to schedule the opening of a command line to run task in another pc. But I am not able to open them.

AT \\OTHERPC 15:00 "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" BATCHJOB.bat

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I already found the answer, the option /interactive needs to be se

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to point the at command to the batch file, not at the command prompt. Also, you need two backslashes.

for example,

AT \\otherpc 15:00 "C:\temp\batchjob.bat".

Answer (score 1):

What is the error message you are getting ? Do you have sufficient privilege to run AT ? I think you need local admin to run an at command on the local computer and domain admin to run it on another machine.

Comment: I want to use the cmd so that the next user of the PC can see the job that was run